# what is the correct way to use range in regards to loading images in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Alright..  I rewrote it but I'm still having problems with the random.choice
 I understand whats its trying to do and i do want the radom.choice to be for the reset when the sprite leaves the screen; but its not being random...

```
class Planets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            imageFiles = ["planet_{}.gif".format(num) for num in range (1,4)]
            for files in imageFiles:
                self.image = pygame.image.load(files)    
            self.image.convert()
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.x = 700
            self.y = 50
            self.dx = -5

        def update(self):
            self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)
            self.x += self.dx
            if self.x <= -800:
                self.reset()

        def reset(self):
            self.x = 800
            self.image = random.choice(files)
            self.y = random.randrange(0, screen.get_height())
```

Comment: self.x = 700. self.x = .5. self.x = 800. Huh? Make up your mind.

Comment: Hey Lennart: The breakdown is self.x = 700 is the starting position of the image.. 700 over 50 down then the self.dx(difference in x) is -5..  so to the opposite direction(move left) 5 pixels..  lastly when the images moves left to be a total of 800 pixels away from its starting point it starts back over at 800 pixels over to screen right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
for files in imageFiles:
    self.image = pygame.image.load(files)
```

Loads one image into `self.image`, and then replaces it with the others, one after the other. I don't know what you intended but this loop doesn't do anything useful.

And this code: `self.image = random.choice(files)` - should fail entirely, because `files` doesn't exist in that function. Even if it's somehow referencing the files variable in the init function, it's just a string, so self.image would end up being 1 character, rather than an actual image.

I'd try something like this (some code left out):

```
(in __init__)
self.files = []
for files in imageFiles:
    self.files.append(pygame.image.load(files))
for img in self.files:
    img.convert()
self.reset()

(in reset)
self.image = random.choice(self.files)
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Answer (score 1):

i'd do this:

```
files = ["planet_{}.gif".format(num) for num in range (1,4)]
for filename in files:
    f = open (filename) .... and so on
```

and when you have a list of all images do

```
image_to_display = random.choice (image_list)
```